# Lower and upper bound on $\prod_{i=1}^n(2^i+1)$

Tags: combinatorics, upper-lower-bounds

Consider
$$\prod_{i=1}^n(2^i+1)=(2+1)(2^2+1)(2^3+1)\dots(2^n+1)$$
I am looking for upper and lower bounds on this expression.

A simple lower bound is
$$ \prod_{i=1}^n(2^i+1)\geq \prod_{i=1}^n(2^i)=2^{n(n+1)/2}$$
which just takes the leading term.

---

**Edit: As suggested in the comments, we can rewrite the product as
$$ \prod_{i=1}^n(2^i+1)= 2^{n(n+1)/2} \times \prod_{i=1}^n(1+ 1/2^i)$$
with the product on the RHS being studied extensively in the linked answer and others posted in the comments. It turns out that
$$  \prod_{i=1}^{n=\infty}(1+ 1/2^i) \approx 2.384231029 $$**

---

I can do a bit better by considering all products where I select a single 1
$$(1)(2^2)\dots\dots(2^n),\\ (2^1)(1)(2^3)\dots(2^n),\\(2^1)(2^2)(1)
(2^4)\dots(2^n),\\\dots$$
This gives
$$ \prod_{i=1}^n(2^i+1) \geq \left(\sum_{k=0}^n2^{-k}\right) \times \prod_{i=1}^n(2^i) = (2-2^{-n})\times2^{n(n+1)/2}$$
Now, I could go on to consider products where one selects two 1s, three 1s and so on. Here, my combinatorics shuts down...
Also apparently my expression is related to the $q$-Pochhammer symbol $(a,q)_n$ as
$$\prod_{i=1}^n(2^i+1)= 1/2 \times (-1,2)_{n+1}$$. But searching for asymptotics or bounds didnt help me much yet.

I am looking for the best lower bound you can get. In particular is
$$\prod_{i=1}^n(2^i+1) \geq \tfrac{5}{2} \times 2^{n(n+1)/2}\; ???$$
Also, apparently the following upper bound holds
$$\prod_{i=1}^n(2^i+1)\leq 3 \times 2^{n(n+1)/2}$$
How to show that one?

Comment: @Peter Yes it was a typo, it should read $2-2^{-n}$. I edited.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you are looking for lower and upper bounds of $\prod_{k=1}^n (1 + 1/2^k)$, so this might be of some use: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2810633/42969. – According to the comments, it converges to $\approx 2.384231029$.

Comment: @MartinR I observed this numerically as well with PARI/GP

Comment: Here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2506534/42969 is a simple proof that the factors is less than $e$ (and therefore less than $3$).

Comment: $\prod_{k=1}^n (1 + 1/2^k)$ is increasing in $n$, so that $3/2$ is the lower bound, and $\prod_{k=1}^\infty (1 + 1/2^k)$ is the upper bound. Should we close this as a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1924882/42969 ?

Comment: @MartinR I think, everything has been said.

Comment: @MartinR Hey, thanks for your help. Yes, the links to the questions you posted completely answered my question! Feel free to close.